# Manually modified node graph visualization?

Tags: ros, visualization, node, print

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to ROS and I would like to know whether it is possible to get the graph visualization of ROS nodes like in rqt_graph in a file format which can be further modified manually (nodes rearranged, etc.) and printed properly?

Thank you very much
myro

EDIT: I simply want a graph file of my current running nodes in order to print the visualization on paper in a proper format. For that, I need some graph description file where i can visually move nodes in order to fit them on a A4-paper. (It also makes sense for documenting the "stack". I cannot influence the layout in rqt_graph.)
I do not want to change my actual running nodes/topics. It just would be nice to get a file describing the nodes-graph which can be postprocessed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/184142/manually-modified-node-graph-visualization?/) by [myro](https://answers.ros.org/users/19152/myro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rqt_graph` has a button (in the upper right corner) to save to a file (specifically, a [DOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29) graph file). The dot file is a text file that you can open with any editor and modify as you wish, then run through `dot` (part of [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) software) to put it another format.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2014-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [myro](https://answers.ros.org/users/19152/myro/) on 2014-07-09**:
oops. how could i miss those. thanks a lot.